# How to make p-calender enable/disable based on ngxPermissions

Tags: angular, primeng-calendar

```
<p-calendar  id="editFFdate" [required]="true" [showIcon]="true" [(ngModel)]="editFFdate" name="editFFdate" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="2000:2030" showButtonBar="true">
      </p-calendar>
```

How to make p-calender enable only for specific roles using *ngxPermissions

Comment: What do you mean can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

You can add p-calendar in ng-template eg:

```
<div *ngxPermissionsOnly="['ADMIN', 'GUEST']">
  <p-calendar  id="editFFdate" [required]="true" [showIcon]="true" 
    [(ngModel)]="editFFdate" name="editFFdate" [monthNavigator]="true" 
     [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="2000:2030" showButtonBar="true">
  </p-calendar>
</div>
```